# Pass variable from a ViewController to a UIPopoverControllerView iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am having problems passing a variable from a view controller to a UIPopoverViewcontroller

is the logic not the same as passing data between two usual viewControllers?

i.e setting a variable in view1 & view2 and synthesising then presenting the PopoverView pass the variable from view1 to view2?

I am really struggling with this I have read a little about protocols but seems overkill if it would work like a usual view controller?

An example

```
    self.optionsPopover.delegate = self;
    popOverViewController = [[PopOverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PopOverViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.optionsPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popOverViewController];

    //dictionary to pass from view1 to view2 which is a popover
    self.popOverViewController.statsDict = self.statsDict;
    [self.optionsPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
    [self.optionsPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:optionsButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: It is the same, but you set the properties before you present it. Did you create a custom class for the popover to put your properties in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code except you are setting delegate of popOver before creating  popover. I have changed the order. And check your dictionary is nil or not

```
self.popOverViewController = [[PopOverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PopOverViewController" bundle:nil];

 //dictionary to pass from view1 to view2 which is a popover
//self.popOverViewController.statsDict = self.statsDict;

 self.popOverViewController.testString = @"testing"; // This is for testing only

 self.optionsPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popOverViewController];
 self.optionsPopover.delegate = self;

[self.optionsPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
[self.optionsPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:optionsButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: No. It's the order of calling `initWithContentViewController` after setting the custom property. See my answer for the proper solution.

Comment: @AttilaH In my answer iam also setting the property before creating popover controller. Whats wrong in that??

Comment: The solution has nothing to do with when you set the delegate. That's it! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `UIPopOverViewController` will allow  you to show your own `UIViewController` (act as a container). Like a `UINavigationController` that receives a `UIViewController`. What exactly do you want to do in your `UIPopoverViewController`?

Comment: I have provided an example of passing a dictionary from view1 to view2 which is the popoverviews view controller

Comment: Why are you initing a `UIPopOverController` with another one?

Comment: optionsPopover is the UIPopoverController and popOverViewController is the view that sits in the popover

Comment: Next time change a bit more the name of your classes (`PopOverController`vs `UIPopoverController`). Can you check the value of your `self.statsDict`?

Comment: agreed sorry wasnt clear. self.statsDict does contain the values I would expect however when checking the dict has be passed to the popoverview in its viewdidload the dict is null so its not passing the value. The dict is init and alloced on both classes before trying to access it..

Comment: How are you checking those values?

Answer (score 0):

After `initWithContentViewController`, your `popOverViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method is already called (and that time the `statsDict` property is `nil`).

So either set the property before the initializer is called or write a custom setter like:

```
- (void)seStatsDict(NSDictionary *)statsDict
{
    _statsDict = statsDict;
    if (self.view) {
        // Set UILabel texts, etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry it made no difference